# Entity Framework Change Primary Key Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF 6.0 Code First, and I have this entity:

```
 public class TrainingRespect
 {
    [Key]
    public int RespectId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateWhenRespected { get; set; }

    #region

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public Guid TrainingId { get; set; }
    public Trening Training { get; set; }

    #endregion
 }
```

And I would like to change it's Primary Key (RespectId) from int to GUID / string / long.

What is easiest way of doing this ? Can I just change type and EF migrations will take care of everything or it should be done some other way ?

Comment: Looks like you've got an idea of something you could do. Have you tried it? The answer should be 'yes'.

Comment: @JTolley No, because I was 99% sure that answer should be "no".I had some bad experiences before with older versions of EF whit this. Anyway after reading your comment I tried to change it from int to long and string, and both times I got this err: 
`Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
The statement has been terminated.`

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok to actually answer your question. **Yes** you can just change the data type and Migrations should take care of it.

However based off your comments you're having trouble applying this migration. This doesn't negate the above but I'll attempt to help using a bit of guesswork.

If you're using Sql Azure, you must have clustered indexes on all tables. EF6 should create clustered indexes even on string keys. There is a bug with alpha 3 though where it doesn't create a clustered key on the migrations table.

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/435723

See the above link for a description and a workaround.

If you're still having trouble, you can run the following command from the package console:

```
Update-Database -Script
```

This will produce a SQL Script instead of trying to update directly. You can look at this and see if any of the Create Table statements do not have a clustered index on them.

If, for some reason there aren't. You can explicitly modify your migration's CreateTable statement to make the primary key clustered.

```
CreateTable("MyTable", 
    c => new { 
        Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128)
    })
.PrimaryKey(t => t.Id, null, true);
```

Also worth noting: **Guids make terrible clustered indexes**. If you're using GUID keys and have the option, don't cluster on them and have a second clustered index instead.

Comment: For info: the V12 preview version of Azure allows tables without a clustered index http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-preview-whats-new/

Comment: I've tired with fix for alpha 3 bug, now I'm going to try to update to V12 and see what happens, and than I'll try with -Script option, thanks for your answers

Answer (score 4):

Here one solution if you want to changing primary key data type in EF Core:

- Drop the indexes and constraints
- Rename Id to Old Id
- Make new Id of the right datatype
- Run an embedded sql statement to update the foreign keys
- Drop old id
- Create new indexes and constraints

Here is the full article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1193009/Changing-primary-key-data-type-in-EF-Core